# XSLT sum function

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to generate an item that accumulates a total for a given XML input.

The XML input is:

```
<item id="15117180817160" amount="1441.63"/>
<item id="15117180817161" amount="300.10"/>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
 <tr>
   <th scope="col">Nro. de Reclamo</th>
   <th scope="col">Monto $</th>
 </tr>                   
 <xsl:for-each select="item">                
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
          <xsl:value-of select="@item" />
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="width:8%;">
          <xsl:value-of select="@amount" />
        </td>
   </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td align="right">
      Total:
     </td>
     <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(/item/@amount)"/>
     </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

And this is my output:

```
<html xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<body>
<h2></h2>
<table border="1">
 <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>id</th>
    <th>amount</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>15117180817160</td>
    <td>1441.63</td>
    <br/>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>15117180817161</td>
    <td>300.10</td>
    <br/>
</tr>
Total: 0
</table>
```

The result should be Total = 1741,73

How can I implement a sum function that returns the correct total value?

Best Regards
Jorge

Comment: You've already asked this question.  You've also received an answer that mentioned that you ought to move `<xsl:value-of select="sum(/item/@amount)"/>` outside of the loop.  If you have a new question, please [edit] and add a *complete* [mcve] and state how your new issue differs from you old one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(/item/@amount)"/>
```

Do this...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(item/@amount)"/>
```

The initial `/` in the first expression represents the document node, so it would only work if the child root element called `item`. You haven't showed it in your XML sample, but as you have multiple `item` elements, they must be contained within a parent element.